# Mysterious - different speeds at different latitudes of the Sun

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, astrophysics, sun

I recently read here ([Hyperphysics page on Sun](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solar/sun.html#c1)) since the Sun is a gaseous body and hence different latitudes can rotate at varying speeds. Naively, I was guessing that the poles would have faster rotation and hence smaller period of revolution than the equator. This intuition was rooted in the assumption that we start with some preliminary rotating gas, which condenses into a ball, and conservation of angular momentum would impose that 'pieces' near the pole spin faster (because they have a smaller moment of Inertia).

However, as you can read from the hyperlink that it is the equator that spins faster and thus, has a shorter time period. What's the explanation? The only fault which I can find in my assumption/quick calculation is that the density of the gaseous material is NOT uniform, and is much much higher near the poles than at the equator. Is this correct, or is there a different explanation?

Comment: Given that there is substantial shear forces in the interior, assuming the rotation all comes from the original angular momentum falls apart.

Comment: Yes, I agree but that doesn't still explain why the gaseous material at the poles would spin faster than at the equator

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245936/what-causes-the-differential-rotation-of-the-sun has some info.

Comment: Also https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/sunearth/science/solar-rotation.html, http://www.star.bris.ac.uk/bjm/solar/solarrot.html, and http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1974ARA%26A..12...47G

Comment: Thanks a lot. These would be helpful